# Does GCP have an Iac tool just like CloudFormation of AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform

As a big fan of AWS, I think the CloudFormation(CFN) is such a good tool to execute IaC. So I'm interested in if GCP has a similar tool.

Thanks.

Comment: Deployment Manager is a very good tool just like CloudFormation. Google Cloud also promotes HashiCorp Terraform which is very good also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Google Cloud platform provides [Deployment Manager](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/) to write and provision your Infrastructure as a Code.

If you want can go through this blog to how to get start with Deployment Manager it's as simple as CloudFormation you can code everything in YAML :
https://medium.com/google-cloud/2018-google-deployment-manager-5ebb8759a122